# Extracting Prices with Regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm look to extract prices from a string of scraped data.

I'm using this at the moment:

```
re.findall(r'£(?:\d+\.)?\d+.\d+', '£1.01')
['1.01']
```

Which works fine 99% of the time. However, I occasionally see this:

```
re.findall(r'£(?:\d+\.)?\d+.\d+', '£1,444.01')
['1,444']
```

I'd like to see `['1444.01']` ideally.

This is an example of the string I'm extracting the prices from.

```
'\n                £1,000.73                \n\n\n                + £1.26\nUK delivery\n\n\n'
```

I'm after some help putting together the regex to get `['1000.73', '1.26']` from that above string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may grab all the values with `'£(\d[\d.,]*)\b'` and then remove all the commas with

```
import re
s = '\n                £1,000.73                \n\n\n                + £1.26\nUK delivery\n\n\n'
r = re.compile(r'£(\d[\d.,]*)\b')
print([x.replace(',', '') for x in re.findall(r, s)])
# => ['1000.73', '1.26']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/sq0uq2)

The `£(\d[\d.,]*)\b` pattern finds `£` and then captures a digit and then any 0+ digits/`,`/`.`, as many as possible, but will backtrack to a position where a word boundary is.

Comment: Good solution - I'll give this a go. Thanks Wiktor